# Android: How to add Buttons to a Layout programmatically(with Buttons to be seen in the XML-View)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button

as the title states, i do want to add Buttons to a ConstraintLayout programmaticaly, whic implies,
added Buttons are to be seen within the XML-File.

**XML File:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/idMain">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Code for adding Buttons:**

```
ConstraintLayout cst = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.idMain);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Hallo Welt");
cst.addView(btn);
```

**Issue:** Added Button is nowhere to be seen within the XML-File.
**Question**: How to append the Button to the XML-File ?

**UP**

Answer (score 0):

Use this code
XML

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
         android:id="@+id/ly_id"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java code to add button programetically.

```
    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.ly_id);

    //set the properties for button
    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setText("Button");
    btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

    //add button to the layout
    layout.addView(btnTag);
```